# Capturar registro modificado en SQL Server

Tags: sql, server

Quiero hacer un `trigger` en una tabla específica para que "capture" algún registro modificado.
Por ejemplo:
Al momento de ingresar una persona, se insertará en esta tabla:

```
Select DNI, NOMBRE, DIRECCION, EMAIL * from personas
```

Pero supongamos que me confundí de DNI y quiero modificarlo.
Estaría necesitando hacer un `trigger` que me avise si hubo una modificación en una persona en general..

Saludos

Comment: Ornella, veo que llevas un año en el sitio, seguro ya sabes cómo funciona. Necesitamos ver qué has intentado. Dijiste que querías crear un Trigger. Qué ocurrió? No funcionó? Cuál era el resultado esperado? Cuál resultado obtuviste?

Comment: Todavía no lo pude hacer ya que no sabría si existe alguna función para esto.

Comment: No es así. Un trigger no te avisa de nada. Puede coger el registro "insertado" y modificarlo. Por ejemplo. Si mete un dni sin letra, y en el trigger capturas esa inserción. y le calculas la letra automaticamente.....eso si es posible, Por tanto insertas, y antes realmente de que puedas ver confirmada la inserción, el trigger puede o no modificar la misma. [Trigger After Insert](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/).

Comment: Si, como dice Javi, necesitas ser notificada de los cambios que ocurren en tu base de datos, checa [este artículo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/working-with-sql-notification/), tal vez tenga información de utilidad. Otra forma puede ser utilizando [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr)